# How to use BETWEEN mysql operator with the postCondition method?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, between

I'm new to cakePHP and I need to use the `controller::postConditions` method with the `BETWEEN` operator but I can't figure out how.

I tried this syntax, as I have read on the `controller::find` documentation :

```
$this->postConditions($this->data, array('Client.client_date_inscription BETWEEN ? AND ?'=>array($this->data['Client']['client_date_inscriptionD'],$this->data['Client']['client_date_inscriptionF'])))
```

the form input is created like so :

```
echo $form->input('Client.client_date_inscriptionD',array('label'=>false,'type'=>'text','class'=>'toDatePicker'));
```

but this throws this error :

```
SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Client.client_date_inscriptionD' in 'where clause'
```

So my question is, how do you use the `BETWEEN` operator with `postConditions` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@boobyWomack I changed the uppercase D and F, it's something I've tried randomly.

I tried many things and lurked in the cookbook to find the answer.
I found how to do this by chance actually, not in the postConditions doc.

Here's the postConditions call :

```
 $this->postConditions($this->data, array('Client.client_nom' => 'LIKE', 'Client.client_prenom' => 'LIKE', 'Client.client_email' => 'LIKE','Client.client_date_inscription'=>'BETWEEN ? AND ?'))
```

However, the Client.client_date_inscription input in the view should provide an array of 2 values.
I did it with a syntax I've found in the cookbook :

```
$form->input('Client.client_date_inscription.0',array('label'=>false,'type'=>'text','class'=>'toDatePicker'))
$form->input('Client.client_date_inscription.1',array('label'=>false,'type'=>'text','class'=>'toDatePicker'))
```

Another way is to change manually the value of `$this->data['Client']['client_date_inscription']` in the controller, but that wasn't relevant in my case.

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue, since it's not very clear in the cookbook nor in the API.

Comment: i n some ways it seems unclear for cake to have used this almost "SaveAll" style syntax in the context of a find - as I would not have guessed it would be this way - but it is also pretty nifty, so kudos to the cake devs once again for providing a handy method :-)

Answer (score 1):

hi is your column really got the uppercase D and the uppercase F at the end? I would change that if you are able! Doesnt seem to fit with cake conventions of naming.

that said it is obviously possible to use these names with Cake.

**I think you should first try to get the right query with a normal find from Cake.** PostCondtions method is a advanced shortcut function really, and it might be better in this case to try to get it working in standard find way.

then you can use the debug output of the SQL from normal find() to see where it differs with the PostCondtions. Maybe that will help.

I also notice the syntax in the docs for PostConditions hint at something like 'referrer'=>'BETWEEN' (array parameters needed basically - so read the API or actual docs for the function and you might find the option you need there!)

Someone on IRC may know something obscure like this- did you try there?

good luck, please post back if you find the answer I would like to know :)

Comment: Hi, I found the answer, I posted it if you're interested.
Thanks for your help btw !

Comment: hey well done, you could have marked me up for at least my suggestion to use normal method, since I think this was a case of "learning to walk before learning to run" :) nice one you found it by the way!

Comment: Sorry but I think I didn't have the rights to upvote your comment before (not enough reputation score maybe ?), it is done now :) thanks again.